# Form C# checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

just need to make it so it will delete records from a list (records) under a threshold that the user set c# forms

here is my code, any advice or help is great, its only for uni assignment so haven't learn a lot yet thanks

```
 private void FindAndDeleteByCash()
 {
      for (int i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
      {  
           if (CreditCheckBox.Checked == true)
           {
                if (Convert.ToDouble(BalanceRequired.Text) > records[i].CreditBalance)
                {
                     records.Remove(records[i]);
                }
           }
      }    
 }
```

Comment: btw `if (CreditCheckBox.Checked == true)` is the same as `if (CreditCheckBox.Checked)` but second is shorter

Comment: @pes502 its not quite the same, an if statement needs a boolean to equate, `CheckBox.Checked` provides that, `== true` first checks if a boolean is equal to true and returns another boolean, but its an unnecessary check as you already have your required result

Answer (score 3):

Since `records.Count` *changes* after *each deletion*, `for(int i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)` goes wrong. You can amend the inner *for loop* if you change it to *backward* one:

```
 private void FindAndDeleteByCash() {
   for (int i = records.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) // <- Backward loop
     if (CreditCheckBox.Checked && (Convert.ToDouble(BalanceRequired.Text) > records[i].CreditBalance))
       records.Remove(records[i]); // <- records.RemoveAt(i); looks better here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`records.Count` is changed in your loop, so you might want to put it outside the loop.

also, you can join the `if` statements to 1:

```
    private void FindAndDeleteByCash()
    {
        int recCount = records.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < recCount; i++)
        {  
            if (CreditCheckBox.Checked == true &&
                 Convert.ToDouble(BalanceRequired.Text) > records[i].CreditBalance)
            {
                    records.Remove(records[i]);
            }
         }    
    }
```

Comment: thanks but for some reason when i go to run it, it wont have any errors but instead once i click the button the program crashes

Comment: @user2758012 can you tell me what's the program says when it's crashing? and in what line? in fact if you can share the entire stack trace in the question that will be great

Answer (score 0):

For framework 3.5 or above: (untested)

```
 private void FindAndDeleteByCash()
 {
      Double balance = Convert.ToDouble(BalanceRequired.Text);

      if(CreditCheckBox.Checked == true)
      {
          var rec =  records.Where((rec) => rec <= balance) // Using LINQ
          // print 'rec' to verify, it will contain only related result sets.
      }  
 }
```